# How to reuse Ammonite REPL's sc files in a sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt, jupyter, sbt-plugin, ammonite

I have some reusable Ammonite REPL's `sc` files that were used in some Jupyter Scala notebooks.

Now I am creating a standalone application built from sbt. I hope I can reuse these existing `sc` files in the sbt project.

Is it possible to share these `sc` files for both Jupyter Scala/Ammonite REPL and sbt projects? How to make `scala` sources and `sc` files compile together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [Import.scala](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Import.scala), a Scala compiler plugin that enables magic imports.

With the help of **Import.scala**, code snippets in a `.sc` file can be loaded into Scala source file in a sbt project with the same syntax as Ammonite or Jupyter Scala:

Given a `MyScript.sc` file.

```
// MyScript.sc
val elite = 31337
```

Magic import it in another file.

```
import $file.MyScript
```

It works.

```
assert(MyScript.elite == 31337)
```